# Can't write to Binary File C++

Tags: c++98

So , I am currently Doing an project where i need to create a file to store contacts , read them , modify .....
Everything was working perfectly but after a few days once i opened and ran the file again it screwed up everything it just wont write the file
once i write the file , all i get is 100 blank spaces and i know why 100 becuase each data member in my class is 20 and therefore i have 5 so 5x20=100
But i dont knoq why this is not writing NOTE: This was working perfectly before
,also i tried many things but it dosnt want to write....

code:

```
void contacts::createnew()
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("contacts.c",ios::binary||ios::out);
    input();
    display();
    fout.write( (char*) &c, sizeof(c));
    fout.close();
    view();
    cout<<fout.good()<<fout.bad()<<fout.fail();
}

class contacts
{
    private:
        char name[20];
        addline_1[20];
        addline_2[20];
        email_id[20];
        char ph_no[10];
        mob_no[10];
    public:
        void init();

        //get contacts details by input
        void input()
        {
            // Implementation here...
        }
        void display()
        {
            // Implementation here...
        }

        void createnew();
        void view();
}
```

Comment: it will be nice to look at whole code that you try run

Comment: the whole code contains 6000 words more than 200 lines , so i just wrote which is necessary...

Comment: where do you close stream? what is **c** variable?

Comment: i used constructor method to open the file , c is an object of the class contacts

Comment: do you close the file after data has been written?

Comment: ok that was old code, check now